# Improve running speed of FullSimplify function

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, filtering

How can I make this code faster? The checking with `FullSimplify` takes a lot of time.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
myPrint[args__, {style__}] := Print[Row[{args}, BaseStyle -> {style}]]
f1[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, b5_, b6_, 
   d_] := -(((a5 + a2 d - a5 d) (b4 + b1 d - b4 d) - (a4 + a1 d - 
          a4 d) (b5 + b2 d - b5 d))/(-(a6 + a3 d - a6 d) (b5 + b2 d - 
          b5 d) + (a5 + a2 d - a5 d) (b6 + b3 d - b6 d)));
f2[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, b5_, b6_, 
   d_] := (a4 b6 - a6 (-1 + d) (b4 (-1 + d) - b1 d) + 
     d (a4 b3 - a3 b4 + a1 b6 - 2 a4 b6 + 
        a3 (-b1 + b4) d + (a1 - a4) (b3 - b6) d))/(a6 (-1 + 
        d) (b5 (-1 + d) - b2 d) - a5 (-1 + d) (b6 (-1 + d) - b3 d) + 
     d (a2 b6 (-1 + d) - a2 b3 d + a3 (b5 + b2 d - b5 d)));
tup1 = Tuples[{{0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 
     1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, 1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0, 
     1}, {-1, 0, 1}}];
myPrint["The total number of cases: ", 
 Length[tup1], {FontSize -> 25, FontWeight -> Bold, 
  Background -> LightGreen}]
tupn = Pick[tup1, 
   Quiet[FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == 1] || 
       FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == f1[##, d]] || 
       FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == (1 - f1[##, d]) ] || 
       FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == (f1[##, d] - 1) ] & @@@ tup1]];
myPrint["The number of removed cases: ", 
 Length[tup1] - Length[tupn], {FontSize -> 25, FontWeight -> Bold, 
  Background -> LightGreen}]
```

Comment: Have you tried `Simplify`?  It's probably faster and sufficiently robust on rational functions. Also, you could be simplifying `f2` four times and `f1` three times, which seems likely to be wasteful (it might not be, but it probably is).

Comment: I tried but it's still very slow. How can I reduce the number of simplifying?

Comment: With `Simplify` only two cases remained out of `104 976` so I think `Simplify` doesn't work.

Comment: How many cases are you supposed to get?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I don't know exactly but I expect it would be more than several hundreds.

Comment: Hmm, with `Simplify`, out of the first ten tuples in `tup1`, I get that six cases remain and four are removed. I don't know how you got only two. -- When both `f1` and `f2` evaluate to `0/0`, is the tuple to be discarded?

Comment: @MichaelE2 would be better to discard that cases too, discard if either one evaluate to `0/0`. My code above didn't include that but I'll remove them anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of filtering symbolically, we can filter numerically to remove a large number of undesired tuples.  Since the numerators and denominators are quadratic polynomials, the rational functions are determined by their values at five distinct points.  To keep things in machine integers, we write a rational function as an ordered pair and code some of the algebra by hand.  (Has someone already written a package that implements rational arithmetic in terms of ordered pairs?)

```
f12[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, b5_, b6_, 
   d_] := {-((a5 + a2 d - a5 d) (b4 + b1 d - b4 d) - (a4 + a1 d - 
         a4 d) (b5 + b2 d - b5 d)),  (* numerator *)
   (-(a6 + a3 d - a6 d) (b5 + b2 d - b5 d) + (a5 + a2 d - a5 d) (b6 + 
        b3 d - b6 d))};              (* denominator *)

f22[a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, b1_, b2_, b3_, b4_, b5_, b6_, 
   d_] := {(a4 b6 - a6 (-1 + d) (b4 (-1 + d) - b1 d) + 
     d (a4 b3 - a3 b4 + a1 b6 - 2 a4 b6 + a3 (-b1 + b4) d +
     (a1 - a4) (b3 - b6) d)),        (* numerator *)
   (a6 (-1 + d) (b5 (-1 + d) - b2 d) - a5 (-1 + d) (b6 (-1 + d) - b3 d) + 
     d (a2 b6 (-1 + d) - a2 b3 d +
     a3 (b5 + b2 d - b5 d)))};       (* denominator *)

cf1 = Compile[{{a1, _Integer, 1}, {a2, _Integer, 1}, {a3, _Integer, 
     1}, {a4, _Integer, 1}, {a5, _Integer, 1}, {a6, _Integer, 
     1}, {b1, _Integer, 1}, {b2, _Integer, 1}, {b3, _Integer, 
     1}, {b4, _Integer, 1}, {b5, _Integer, 1}, {b6, _Integer, 
     1}, {d, _Integer}},
   Evaluate@f12[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, d]];
cf2 = Compile[{{a1, _Integer, 1}, {a2, _Integer, 1}, {a3, _Integer, 
     1}, {a4, _Integer, 1}, {a5, _Integer, 1}, {a6, _Integer, 
     1}, {b1, _Integer, 1}, {b2, _Integer, 1}, {b3, _Integer, 
     1}, {b4, _Integer, 1}, {b5, _Integer, 1}, {b6, _Integer, 
     1}, {d, _Integer}},
   Evaluate@f22[a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, d]];
test = Compile[{{pair1, _Integer, 1}, {pair2, _Integer, 1}}, 
   If[Last@pair1 == 0 || Last@pair2 == 0,
    1,
    With[{
      a1 = pair1[[1]], (* a1/a2 = f1[##, d] *)
      a2 = pair1[[2]],
      b1 = pair2[[1]], (* b1/b2 = f2[##, d] *)
      b2 = pair2[[2]]
      },
     (b1 - b2) *                (* b1/b2=f2[##,d]=1 *)
      (a1 b2 - a2 b1) *         (* b1/b2=f2[##,d]=f1[##,d]=a1/a2 *)
      (a1 b2 + a2 b1 - a2 b2) * (* b1/b2=f2[##,d]=1-f1[##,d]=1-a1/a2 *)
      (a1 b2 - a2 b1 - a2 b2)   (* b1/b2=f2[##,d]=f1[##,d]-1=a1/a2-1 *)
     ]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

res = Fold[Function[{tup, d},
     Pick[tup,
      test[
       cf1[##, d] & @@ Transpose[tup] // Transpose,
       cf2[##, d] & @@ Transpose[tup] // Transpose],
      0
      ]
     ],
    tup1,
    Range[3, 7]
    ]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> (*  {0.068052, Null}  *)
> ```

```
Length@res
```

> ```
> (*  19544  *)
> ```

Check symbolically:

```
res = Pick[res, 
    Quiet[FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == 1] || 
        FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == f1[##, d]] || 
        FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == (1 - f1[##, d])] || 
        FullSimplify[f2[##, d] == (f1[##, d] - 1)] & @@@ 
      res]]; // AbsoluteTiming
Length@res
```

> ```
> (*  {10.7007, Null}  *)
> (*  19544  *)
> ```

***Addendum: Symbolic speed-ups.***

`Simplify` is usually as robust as `FullSimplify` on rational functions. (I think "usually" can be replaced by "always," in fact.)

```
res = Pick[res, 
    Quiet[Simplify[f2[##, d] == 1] || 
        Simplify[f2[##, d] == f1[##, d]] || 
        Simplify[f2[##, d] == (1 - f1[##, d])] || 
        Simplify[f2[##, d] == (f1[##, d] - 1)] & @@@ 
      res]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> (*  {8.97561, Null}  *)
> ```

Nesting `Simplify` sometimes speeds things up.  There's no real way to be sure without testing.  If the first `Simplify` simplifies a lot, then it usually will help.  `Simplify` also caches some results, which can trip up the one who would predict which way is faster.

```
res = Pick[res,
    Quiet[
     With[{sf1 = Simplify[f1[##, d]], sf2 = Simplify[f2[##, d]]},
        Simplify[sf2 == 1] || Simplify[sf2 == sf1] || 
         Simplify[sf2 == (1 - sf1)] || Simplify[sf2 == (sf1 - 1)]
        ] & @@@ res]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> (*  {5.78182, Null}  *)
> ```

```
res = Pick[res,
    Quiet[With[{sf2 = Simplify[f2[##, d]]},
        Simplify[sf2 == 1] || (* won't go on to simplify f1[] if True *)
         With[{sf1 = Simplify[f1[##, d]]}, 
          Simplify[sf2 == sf1] || Simplify[sf2 == (1 - sf1)] || 
           Simplify[sf2 == (sf1 - 1)]
          ]] & @@@ res]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> (*  {5.05181, Null}  *)
> ```

Comment: What does `1` in `{a1, _Integer, 1}` mean? Also could you explain a bit `pair1`, `pair2`?

Comment: @anhnha In `Compile`, `{var, type, arraydepth}` declares the variable `var` to be an array of type `type` and depth `arraydepth`.  A list has depth `1`, a matrix depth `2`, and so on. --  A `pair1` should be a list of length two of the form `{num, den}`, where `num/den = f1[..]` and similarly for `pair2` and `f2[]`.  Thus `pair1[[1]] = num` and `pair[[2]] = den`. I added some comment I hope will clarify. Also note that X*Y=0 is equivalent to X=0 or Y=0. So the product is zero if any of the factors are zero.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you choose `1` as `arraydepth` for `a1` while `a1` is just a number?

Comment: @anhnha I thought you meant the code for any of the `Compile` functions.  I misunderstood.  The functions `cf1` and `cf2` are called `cf1[##, d]&@@Transpose[tup]`, which means `a1` is a list of integers.  Since `Transpose[tup]` is a list of twelve lists, one list for each of `a1,..., b6`.  Each of the twelve lists becomes an argument to `cf1`.  This works because `Plus` and `Times` can operate on lists (and it helps here because they are extremely efficient on lists).

Comment: Thanks. The way that functions `cf1` and `cf2` are called makes sense that their inputs are lists. However, I'm confused this part too. `cf1 = Compile[{{a1, _Integer, 1}, {a2, _Integer, 1}, ...]` In this function you're declare that individual variable `a1`, `a2` are lists?

Comment: I forgot to mention that `d` is not   an `integer` but a `real` number but that doesn't seem to affect running speed much.

Comment: I think I'm stuck at this `Since Transpose[tup] is a list of twelve lists, one list for each of a1,..., b6.`. Where is `tup` defined?

Comment: From the definition of `f12`, it's clear that `a1` is a number but it's a bit confusing as you said above `a1` is a list.

Comment: `tup` is the argument to `Function`. The first time in `Fold`, `tup` is equal to `tup1` and `d` is `3`; `tup` has dimensions `{104976, 12}`, so that `Transpose[tup]` has dimensions `{12, 104976}` and the first 12 arguments to `cf1` in `cf1[##, d] & @@ Transpose[tup]` are lists of length `104976`. The second time, `tup` is the output of the first `Function[]`, which has dimensions `{22080, 12}`, and `d` is `4`, etc. -- Try `f12[{5,7,9},{6,3,2},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},{2,8,3},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},{5,7,9},3]]`: `a1` can be an integer or a list b/c `Plus`/`Times` are `Listable`

Comment: @anhnha Sorry it's so confusing. There is a tension between clarity and speed. Translating boolean tests to vectorized arithmetic obscures simple boolean tests on single numbers in cute arithmetic tricks on lists of numbers. But it's very fast by comparison. It's a skill, which means it takes time and effort to learn. I learned it on this site by taking someone else's good answer and trying to make it better. Whether I succeeded or failed, I learned something about faster and slower computations.

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it again if I can make sense of it. I feel I'm already better by trying to understand the answers here.

Comment: I think you assigned `Range[3, 7]` for different `d` values. In my case, `d` is a real variable. I tried to replace `Range[3, 7]` with `d` above but got error `Fold::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 3 in...`

Comment: @anhnha The argument in position 3 should be a list. If you want `d = 0.123`, say, use `{0.123}` in `Fold`. (Since `d` was not given any value in the question, your given code using `Pick` & `FullSimplify` was checking whether the expressions were equal as rational functions. My code does the same thing, based on interpolation theory, by checking values at five distinct real numbers. Since integers are also real numbers, I could use them for my real numbers. It was convenient for efficiency to use numbers of type `Integer` and simultaneously avoid round-off error messing up the comparisons.)

Comment: Actually the `d` in my code is a symbol so all the expressions are functions of `d`. `d` can be any real value from `0` to `1`.  So with this condition, is there any way to make the code above work?

Comment: @anhnha It already does. It picks the tuples such that `f2[##, d] == 1 || f2[##, d] == f1[##, d] || f2[##, d] == (1 - f1[##, d]) || f2[##, d] == (f1[##, d] - 1)` is true for all real numbers `d`.  That's what the interpolation theory says: Rational functions of degree 2 over degree 2, if they agree at 2+2+1=5 different points, then they are identical functions for all real numbers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118655/discussion-between-michael-e2-and-anhnha).